# Soldering nickel wiring to nickel plated brass with electric arc

Tags: soldering

Oke, this is probably a simple question, although i cannot find it on the great internet.

I was in a factory that solders wires to a jack plug, as can be seen in this video from 2:20:
http://www.tudou.com/programs/view/YL5JebwX-Ac/

The soldering is different than my standard soldering iron at home which is always hot.
Where this iron only heats up at contact with some kind of spark or arc.

What is the name of this soldering technique?
What is the name of the soldering iron tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That technique is called [**resistance soldering**](http://www.resistancesoldering.com/). The tool is called a "soldering iron", but obviously its construction is different from heat-based soldering.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that it is difficult to google for where to buy a cheap resistance soldering iron, which results in: "Soldering iron with ant oxidation resistance tip...".
Where would one buy such a special soldering iron?